# Lightningjs to load and access the methods of a Js in separate window namespace?

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-namespaces

I refer [https://github.com/olark/lightningjs] to load the js in separate window namespace .

I have tested a script file named as sample.js like below need to be load in separate window namespace.

```
function testjs(){
console.log("sample");

}
```

I include the lightningjs-embed.js and lightining-bootstrap.js in my html.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>testing light js</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lightningjs-master/lightningjs-embed.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lightningjs-master/lightningjs-bootstrap.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">/*{literal}<![CDATA[*/
/*** lightningjs-embed.min.js ***/
window.piratelib = lightningjs.require("piratelib","js/sample.js");
/*]]>{/literal}*/</script>

console.log("modules",lightningjs.modules);
piratelib("testjs");
```

In console i can view two objects one as lightningjs another one as piratelib. I am expecting to get "sample" in console after calling piratelib("testjs"). But am not getting sample in the console. If try piratelib("testjs") in console it shows

```
function promiseFunction() {
                    console.log("promisdeId",promiseResponseId);
                    promiseFunction.id = promiseResponseId;
                    return modules[namespace].apply(promiseFunction, arguments)
                }
```

instead of actual function in sample.js

```
function testjs(){
console.log("sample");

}
```

Suggest me some ideas to load js under separate window.namespace in order to avoid to js conflict. Clarify me if am calling functions in right way using lightningjs. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This problem definitely needs to be solved.

Answer (score 0):

The functions handled by LightningJS return [promises](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises/A), so:

```
piratelib("testjs").then(function(result) { 
  console.log(result);
}, function(error) {
  // Handle your error
});
```